# how to setstate on button click event in a table

Tags: reactjs

I have master-detail table in react. If I select (or click a button) on a row in the master table, I want to set a state variable with the id of the selected row, which will be used to render the details table for that ID.
However, react does not allow me to use setState in the event function.

```
  constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  customer: {},
  customerRequests: [],
  interactions: [],
  order: [],
  error: '',
  selectedCustomerRequest: ''
}
this.onSelectCustomerRequest = this.onSelectCustomerRequest.bind(this);
```

}

The event function is

```
  onSelectCustomerRequest(id){
console.log(id)
// this.setState({selectedCustomerRequest: id});
```

}

The HTML is

```
          <tr key={item._id} onClick={this.onSelectCustomerRequest(item._id)}>
        <td><button onClick={this.onSelectCustomerRequest(item._id)} /></td>
        <td>{moment(item.orderDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm')}</td>
        <td>{item.genericName}</td>
        <td>{item.quantity}</td>
        <td>{item.priority}</td>
        <td>{interaction.orderStatus}</td>
        <td>{moment(interaction.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm')}</td>
        <td>{interaction.createdBy}</td>
      </tr>
```

if I enable the setState in onSelectCustomerRequest(id){} I get error. secondly I see that the onSelectCustomerRequest() gets executed for every row as I can see it console.log on my terminal.

I want to setState only when I click the button only.

I am sure I am doing a silly mistake somewhere, can you help? Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is that you call the function immediately by add parentheses `()` in the end of method.

To make it work, I would recommend create a closure within a method, so your case it would look like

```
onSelectCustomerRequest(id) {
  return () => {
    console.log(id)
  }
}
```

So you basically by calling `onSelectCustomerRequest` in onClick return a function, which you can fire late.

Comment: excellent... or you can use an arrow function: onClick={() => this.onSelectCustomerRequest(item._id)}

Comment: Brilliant... I knew about this but never used it practically. Now I know the real use of a return within an event. Thanks a million for the quick response. :)

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo 
I agree with you , its best way to give this to function

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I would not recommend to do this, because on every re-render a new anonymous function will be created

Comment: @AlexeiCrecotun, if you map a return of an arrow function, or if you map directly, I think will be created new anonymous function each re-render. But I think, I'm not sure about that. It's an interesting point.